# VBA not updating on Protected Sheet -- Excel Office 365

Tags: excel, office365, vba

There are tons of questions already posted with a similar problem, but none of those solutions works for me.  I'm using Office 365, so maybe it's something that changed there.  Anyway, here is my issue.

I have a file that pulls info from one main tab into other tabs.  On the subsequent tabs, I have VBA that auto-hides rows depending on the value  that was pulled from the main tab.  Anytime the data in the main tab is updated, the subsequent tabs should also update.  I had an issue with making this work, but I worked it out by using another cell to store the previous value that had transferred (comparing them, and running the code any time they were dissimilar).  The problem now is, of course, that it wont run when the tabs are protected.  The tabs need to be protected to prevent end-users from corrupting the formulas and formatting, but I can't make it work with any of the solutions posted on StackOverflow.  My code looks something like this:

```
Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Range("Old Value") <> Range("New Value").Value Then
    Range("Old") = Range("New").Value
    Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    <<Insert code to auto-hide based on "New Value" cell>>

    End If
End Sub
```

I've tried adding `Worksheet.Unprotect Password:=` and `Worksheet.Protect Password:=` commands on either side of the If statement, and I get a 424 Object Required error.  I've tried using the "UserInterfaceOnly = True" command with my password protection, and it changes nothing (still get the trying to change a protected sheet error).  I've tried creating another subroutine for unprotecting and re-protecting, then using a GoTo to run the original subroutine; but that didn't work either.  I see a lot of solutions using ActiveSheet commands, but I don't think I can use them.  I'm updating the main tab, and the action is happening on another tab.  I'm fairly new to coding, and I'm teaching myself as I go; so, I could be missing something obvious.

It works perfectly when unprotected, so I guess I may have to just leave it that way.  I hate wasting time fixing the files when end-users do their best to ruin them, though, so I'd love to leave it protected.

Comment: I had an idea:  maybe instead of using the cell on the protected tab to do the auto-hiding of rows, I could use the original cell where the info is entered on the main tab.  The main tab is normally just hidden, and not protected; so, that may work.  I'll work on figuring out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the final answer, but I seem to have stumbled upon a solution.  Since the only thing I want happening on the protected sheet is for rows to auto-hide, I left row formatting unprotected.  It seems to work fine that way.  You would think there's a way to run your VBA normally without having to jump through hoops because of protection....but, I'll take it for now.